# laravel localization redirects me to mainURL/assets

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, localization, multiple-languages

When I run main url in browser it takes to `mainURL/assets`. But When I put `mainURL/en` or `mainURL/bn`, it works fine. Without selecting "/lang" application shows 403 error.

> 403 Forbidden
>
> nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Config/app.php

```
 'locale' => 'en',
 'locales' => ['en', 'bn','hi','zh','ja'],
 'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

Helper method:

```
public static function switchLang($lang = 'bn')
    {
        $fullUrl = request()->url();
        $segments = request()->segments();
        $partSegment = implode('/', $segments);

        $domain = str_replace('/'.$partSegment, '', $fullUrl);

        $availableLang = config('app.locales');

        if(in_array($lang, $availableLang)) {
            $segments[0] = '/'.$lang;
            $newPartSegment = implode('/', $segments);
            return $domain.$newPartSegment;
        }
        return $fullUrl;
    }
```

view:

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="{{ Helpers::switchLang() }}"> বাংলা </a></li>
       <li><a href="{{ Helpers::switchLang('en') }}"> English </a></li>
       <li><a href="{{ Helpers::switchLang('zh') }}"> 中國 </a></li>
       <li><a href="{{ Helpers::switchLang('hi') }}"> हिंदी  </a></li>
       <li><a href="{{ Helpers::switchLang('ja') }}"> 日本語 </a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Show your code how you do localization

Comment: I have edited the post. Please check.